# HP ProLiant DL320 G6 Server, not entering POST?

Tags: hp-proliant

This is Shahrukh.  I have a server HP ProLiant DL320 G6, OS = Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, Raid-1, iLo-2. The said server went under 2-3 power failure cycles and now the server is stuck at point where when I turn on the server by applying power, the System Health LED on front panel becomes Solid Green and Power Button LED becomes Solid Amber, only PSU fans turned on while other Fans stay off, No Display nothing, the server even not enters POST. It stuck. Please Help.

Regards,

Shahrukh

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dead end of life hardware platform.